How to log startup errors to the console and view them, when Application Insights is not yet configured in Azure Function App?

How to log startup errors to the console and view them, when Application Insights are not yet configured and no ILogger<T> instance is available?

I want to catch and log errors during to startup process, where things can go wrong:

appsettings.json configuration file may not be available
The function may not be able to connect to the SQL Server instance using the "SqlServer" connection string.
GraphServiceClient may not be able to get a token using the DefaultAzureCredential.
...

What's the standard way of catching, logging, and viewing such startup errors?
I cannot depend on Application Insights, as it may not be configured, or it may be wrongly configured. Also, how would I create a ILogger<T> instance in this case (Console.WriteLine(...) doesn't get collected by Application Insights)? So, I will have to rely on Console.WriteLine(...) to log errors in the very early stages of function execution.
Currently, using the Linux consumption plan, I don't see any ways of viewing console output. How can it be displayed, like I would see it in AWS CloudWatch?
Versions:

Azure Function runtime host: 4.x
Language: dotnet-isolated /.NET 8

Program.cs:
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENVIRONMENT") ?? "development";

        Console.WriteLine($"Environment: {environment}");

        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        services.AddDbContext<AssetOwnershipContext>(options =>
        {
            var connectionString = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServer") ?? throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Connection string not found");
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });

        services.AddScoped<IApplicationService, ApplicationService>();
        services.AddScoped<IEmailDispatcher, EmailDispatcher>();
        services.AddTransient<IAssetOwnershipRepository, AssetOwnershipRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<GraphServiceClient>(sp =>
            new GraphServiceClient(
                new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
                {
                    ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true
                })
            )
        );
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

Update:


You can still log startup errors directly even if the azure application insights is not configured in the Azure Function app.

You should use Console.WriteLine to log error messages in your function code.
You can check logs in the local console if you are running locally and also in the Azure Portal > function > monitor or console tab
Set the appropriate logging levels such as to Error, Warning, Info.
Leverage your logging frameworks such as NLog or Serilog for more structured and customizable logging.


Thank you! But I don't have a console blade (please see my updated post for an image). Do you have a link to docs that supports your claims? As console logging doesn't have logging levels, why does it make sense to select it, e.g. "Warning"?

Log Stream option/blade serves your requirement and you can check this SO Link for an example of Console Log Levels Configuration using host.json

@Jawwitha Console.WriteLine() doesn't output a log level, so the host.json values doesn't apply in this case?

Console.WriteLine is for custom error messages and host.json is for built-in log level configuration that works in giving the all levels of logs in both locally and in Azure Portal function app log stream.
